# Is there any way to make an image of my npm packages and use it in my react project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have a project which is using more than 110 npm packages. The project is build in react. Now when I run npm install command it install all the packages but takes a lot of time more than 30 mins even when I have good internet connectivity. Also when all packages are installed it show 500 vulnerabilities in the end. Now I have updated these packages before and it reduce the vulnerable package count to 15 but then after new versions again more than 300 vulnerabilities and speed also decreased.

So my question is that is there any way that I can create exact copy of my npm packages and keep it somewhere so that even when my package's version is deprecated or worst its support has been removed entirely from npm, I will still be able to use that same package in my application?

Also I want to now if there is any possible way to avoid npm install every time when code is moved to production by either creating image of all my npm modules and directly access them or any other way so it will reduce the pipeline execution time and reduce overall production move work?

Comment: Do you, by any chance, use a debug build for production? Normally, you would create a production build, which has no node.js references anymore. With the CRA tools you get the scripts which trigger Webpack to generate a compact image of your app, including all 3rd party libraries.

Comment: I didn't used CRA. I created project from scratch. Also using webpack 3.

Comment: OK, then let webpack create your production build. That will result in just a few minified bundle.js files. I have no experience with that, but you could try to install the `react-scripts` module manually, to get everything configured ready for you to create that build. Just an idea.